# python function optional arguments and skip or not them

Tags: python, function, arguments, option-type

I would like to have a function which is able to compute something if the optional argument are not provide.

My idea is something like this:

```
def Compute(data,**arg):
        #
        if PAR are not provide then
        PAR=gumbel_r.fit(data)
        endif
        #

        QTR = gumbel_r.ppf(data,*PAR)

        return QTR
```

Could someone help me in this?

I have been trying to find this option but I am not able.

Thanks in advance,
Best

Comment: If see no optionnal argument, but a non-fixe number of named-argument, please give example of call you want to do of this method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using variable named argument provision, not optional argument. However, what you want can be achieved in both ways:

Optional argument:

```
def Sort(data, PAR=None):
    if PAR is None:
        return sorted(data)
    else:
        return sorted(data, reverse=PAR)
```

Variable keyword arguments:

```
def Sort2(data, **PAR):
    if not PAR:
        return sorted(data)
    else:
        return sorted(data, **PAR)
```

Result:

```
>>> Sort([1,5,3])
[1, 3, 5]

>>> Sort([1,5,3], True)
[5, 3, 1]

>>> Sort2([1,5,3])
[1, 3, 5]

>>> Sort2([1,5,3], **{'reverse':True})
[5, 3, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create two functions, one with param and another with no param with respective code.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default value for the argument:

```
    def say(word="A default value"):
        print(word)
```

Will result in:

```
    word() #A default value
    word("hi") #hi
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculating default arguments

```
def Compute(data, arg = None):
  if not arg:
     # Computes value for optional argument since values not provided
     arg = gumbel_r.fit(data)
        if PAR are not provide then


  return gumbel_r.ppf(data, arg)
```

**Usage**

```
result = Compute(data)      # will compute a value for arg
result = Compute(data, 15)  # will use 15 as value for arg
```